# How to extract all Oracle Keywords used In a Function/Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, keyword, keyword-search

Is there any easy way to fetch all the Oracle key words used In a function/procedure?

The first thing that strikes me Is to split the text from user_source for the given object name based on space but this will leave few scenarios uncovered like DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO WORLD') etc.,

Is there any other way rather than split by space, dot, paranthesis?

Regards,
KG

Comment: It's even more complicated than that; you will have quoted strings like 'HELLO WORLD' in your example - HELLO and/or WORLD could be keywords, but you don't want them to be seen as "keywords" if they are part of a hardcoded string. Then - even though it is a very bad practice, many people use keywords (like DATE) as column names. You don't want them picked up if they are used as column names. There are many more complications similar to these. So - back one step... WHY do you need to do this?

Comment: I agree and realizing how complicated this is turning out to be. The main reason of starting all this was to develop some kind of security around the code. Though we share the complete product to clients, the code should be In some encrypted form. So, wondering If anything could be developed of such sort. Found several wrap tools but also they can be easily unwrapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use built-in [`ALL_STATEMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_STATEMENTS.html#GUID-36FF82A6-DD4B-45E4-8B46-2ECD38C2AE47)/[`ALL_IDENTIFIERS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1089.htm#REFRN20599).

> **ALL_STATEMENTS describes all SQL statements in stored PL/SQL objects accessible to the user.**

And [The Power of Cloud PL/SQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/the-power-of-cloud-plsql):

> To gather information about PL/SQL identifiers and SQL statements in your code base, execute the following statement in your session

```
ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='identifiers:all, statements:all';
-- function/package compilation

SELECT st.owner,
       st.object_name,
       st.line,
       s.text
  FROM all_statements st join all_source s
    ON ( st.owner = s.owner
   AND st.object_name = s.name
   AND st.line = s.line )
 WHERE st.TYPE IN ('EXECUTE IMMEDIATE', 'OPEN')
```